# Unknown column '1' in 'field list' occurs when inserting data

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `mccfb_validcode` VALUES ('1', 'FBU552U6L9UE1163L92P7', 
'6944866036', 'WEB', 'Success', 'U552U6L9UE1163L92P7', 
'16/02/2018 15:14:06;64;6400050320;180', '64', '180', '6400050320', 
'16/02/2018 15:14:06', '2/19/2018 16:23', '1')
```

Hi, so when I insert this data in my table, it shows this error. Here is the structure of my table and there are 13 fields. Please help! [image]

Comment: i advice you to use `INSERT INTO table (column, column...) VALUES (value, value...)` instead of `INSERT INTO table VALUES  (value, value...)` which is error prone when the table structure is changed in annyway.

Comment: Can you include the create table statement so we can test the insert?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza umm i created this table in phpmyadmin so I don't have create table statement

Comment: But Im sure you can create a script on phpmyadmin. Like [this](https://www.google.co.ve/search?q=phpmyadmin+get+create+table+statement&oq=phpadmin+get+create&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.6798j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

The only visible error I see is that you're inserting string literals into integer columns, and your date literals have an incorrect format.  Try this version:

```
INSERT INTO mccfb_validcode (item, coupon, MSISDN, channel, result, barecode,
    decryptionresult, shopid, points, customer_id, t_date, r_date, no_of_coupon)
VALUES
    (1, 'FBU552U6L9UE1163L92P7', '6944866036', 'WEB', 'Success',
   'U552U6L9UE1163L92P7', '16/02/2018 15:14:06;64;6400050320;180', '64', 180,
    '6400050320', '2018-02-16 15:14:06', '2018-02-19 16:23', 1);
```

In the above insert we explicitly list out the target columns, and therefore the exact values going into those target columns.  The first, last, and fifth-to-last values are integers, with everything else being either varchar or a date.

Note that for the `t_date` and `r_date` columns you were inserting an invalid datetime string.  You should always use an ISO compliant format, e.g. `YYYY-mm-dd`.  So, instead of `16/02/2018 15:14:06`, insert `2018-02-16 15:14:06`.

Comment: thanks! I understand I need to insert an `int` instead of a `string`. Since I am importing this data from a `csv` form in `phpmyadmin`, it automatically generated this code. Do you know how to avoid this when importing from `csv`?

Comment: @BartonDong There must be some way to control the types of the outgoing data.  Perhaps you were using string variables instead of numerical ones when you generated the `INSERT` statement in your PHP code?